# Better search navigation in sublime text editor (fat chunks of text)?

Tags: navigation, editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Having a problem to search effectively in Sublime Text editor. Currently using the latest version of that editor.
After hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> I end with these big blocks, and I would like to navigate to the next file (in the image 1/138) but I don't know how, and using the scrollbar to the right is not precise, and when the files are big it is harder then you can imagine.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Default Functionality:

<kbd>F4</kbd> Open Next Match In View

<kbd>Shift + F4</kbd> Open Previous Match In View

---

### Extended Functionality:

#### Install [BetterFindBuffer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BetterFindBuffer)

<kbd>N</kbd> Navigate To Next File

<kbd>P</kbd> Navigate To Previous File

<kbd>J</kbd> Navigate To Next Match

<kbd>K</kbd> Navigate To Previous Match

Comment: The plugin is little odd but I still like the default functionality very much.

Comment: @prosti : What do you find odd about the plugin?  I find it to be much faster than the default functionality, since it lets you navigate the results buffer without opening files.  The only thing I didn't like about it was that it overrides your theme, but that can be easily resolved by editing the `sublime-settings` file.

Comment: it removes the line numbers, and changes the default background color of search block. Only that.

Comment: @prosti : Save the contents of [**this file**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aziz/BetterFindBuffer/master/Find%20Results.sublime-settings) to `Packages/User/Find Results.sublime-settings` and you can alter those options.